# Why do we should not use an int value for a double variable? (OCA Exam)

Tags: java

I read the book "OCA Java SE 8" of Mala Gupta and there is a question as below:
[image: Mala Gupta - Chapter 2]

As I know that when we declare a double variable with an int value (such as option "e" double a5 = 10), this code still could be compiled, but why in this case option "e" is an incorrect answer?

Comment: The explanation below the question explains it pretty much.

Comment: @MCEmperor The question is to choose the "correct code" and the explanation for option "e" is 'double' is used to store decimal, not an integer. That's sound make sense, but the 'double' still work with 'int' value, why is this code incorrect?

Comment: The question was not which code *compiles* or not; instead, they ask for "correct code to declare and initialize *variables to store whole numbers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an incorrect answer because the integer is converted to double and then stored.

Therefore the ‘variable that stores whole numbers’ part doesn’t apply.

Comment: I opened ".class" file after ".java" file is compiled I realized that the double value here = 10.0D, I guessed the compiler converted this value automatically to double so that's the reason why the code still works even the declared value is int. As @MCEmperor commented above, this asked about "correct to store", not about "can compile or not". Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `double` type is used to store floating point values, not integer values. It can hold the value `10` (as `10.0`), but it can also hold the value `3.452`, which is not an integer. So the statement

```
double x = ..;
```

does not declare a variable for integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You are right : from the compiler, that is valid : `double a5 = 10`.
The compiler widens the `int` to store it as a `double` without any side effect possible since a double can contain any int value.
I think that the question and the expected answers are misleading.

The question should rather refer to the most adapted type to store a value.
And in this case, the e) answer is not correct since it uses a type much bigger than required, that consumes memory for not good reasons. An `int` or even a `short` is enough.

Comment: "Too much memory" is not a good rationale against the answer. The correct rationale is that the question specifies *whole number*.

Comment: @chrylis Don't get your argument. Because for you the whole int number cannot be store as a double ?

Comment: seconded. it is a confusing, underspecified textbook question aiming at learners-by-heart.